# How to compare timestamp with date in HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate

There is a timestamp field  `ordered_ts` mapped to a class. I need to get instances where

1) (`ordered_ts` is null) OR

2) (`ordered_ts` <> current_date)

---

**Here is what i tried. This is `HQL` syntax (not database specific)**

```
SELECT . . . 
WHERE (CAST(coalesce(t.ordered_ts, TO_TIMESTAMP('2000-01-01 00:00:00', 
'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) as DATE) <> CURRENT_DATE)
```

But it throws

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.CastFunction.render(CastFunction
```

---

(PS Underlying database is `mysql`. But I'm looking for `HQL` query)

Answer (score 1):

**For SQL**

Use [FROM_UNIXTIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
SELECT . . . 
WHERE (FROM_UNIXTIME(coalesce(t.ordered_ts, TO_TIMESTAMP('2000-01-01 00:00:00', 
'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) as DATE) <> CURRENT_DATE)
```

**For HQL**

You should convert field `ordered_ts` to Date before using it in query.
See example below:

```
 Date ordered_ts_date= new Date(ordered_ts.getTime());
```

and then

```
SELECT . . . WHERE ordered_ts_date <> CURRENT_DATE)
```

Comment: Thank you. But FROM_UNIXTIME is mysql syntax. Is it going to work in `Hibernate HQL` ?

Comment: So I need to create an extra field `ordered_ts_date` in the mapped bean? Or create `ordered_ts_date` on the fly and insert is in the prepared statement? This seems like an overkill. There should be a simple solution. My bean has the `ordered_ts` field. There should be a way to compare `ordered_ts` with `current_date`

Comment: You should create `ordered_ts_date`  as a method variable and do nullpointer checkng also before inserting to the HQL.